# regexec is not excluding the character

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm trying to match  words which doesn't have a letter 'd' in it , but the regexec is still matching the words with letter d

```
int main(void) {
    regex_t regex;
    char *str = "dabcd";
    char *pattern = "[^d]*";
    
    int ret;

    ret = regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("regex compilation successfully\n");
    } else {
        printf("regex compilation unsuccessful\n");
    }

    ret = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("there is a match\n");
    } else {
        printf("there is no match : %d\n", ret);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

how to solve it ? Is there something wrong with my regex expression?

Comment: `char *pattern = "^[^d]*$";` and `ret = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);`

Comment: Okay let me clear it. If I want to match any charcters(one or more) for the placeholders www.*.com , where * should be any character but shouldn't contain letter 'd' then what regular expression should I use ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: So, what is the pattern you tried to match the string? `[^d]*` is not the pattern. What is the string like? Where `www...com` can appear inside a string?

Comment: so www.abc.com should be valid, www.xyz.com should be valid but www.abcd.com and www.xyzd.com should not be valid. For this what regex should I use?

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/YlOfjV/1).

Comment: Your expression even matches aka.abc.bky! I want www.<any characters except letter d>.com, there has to be www.<word>.com

Comment: It is your regex, not mine, just with anchors. What did *you* try to match `www...com`? Wha do you mean by "character"? A letter? A letter or digit? ...

Answer (score -1):

Your expression only checks that at some point in the string there's a sequence of *zero or more non-`d` characters*. If you want the whole thing to match:

```
^[^d]*$
```

Where that translates to *at the start of the string, zero or more non-`d` characters followed by the end of string*.

This will require altering your compilation code:

```
ret = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED);
```

Where it's noted [in the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp):

> Use POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax when interpreting regex. If not set, POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax is used.

The [man pages for BSD express](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=regcomp&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=freebsd) it even better:

> Compile modern ("extended") REs, rather than the obsolete ("basic") REs that are the default.

So use that mode by default.

Tip: For debugging regular expressions use an explainer tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com).

Comment: Just adding `$` won't work in the OP code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should add an answer with your variant including the `REG_EXTENDED` code. I can only speak to the expression itself, I'm not as familiar with that library.

Comment: This regular expression is correct. I did not touch on the C code changes required to make it work.

Comment: @tadman , what if I want it is middle of a string . Say I want to match ' <some-char> abc <some-char>' -- I want to match this where the middle word should not contain the 'd' character. What regex should I need to use?

Comment: Anything with `*` could be zero-length, so "middle of string" will always match and is basically meaningless. It's like asking "Where in the world can I find zero or more unicorns?" Everywhere. When asking regular expression questions it's very useful for us to see example input and the desired matches, but don't forget you can probably hack around with things like Regex101 to explore on your own a fair bit first.

Comment: Are you just looking for the longest match of non-`d` characters? If so your original pattern does just that. Remember when an expression matches you can extract the *matching text* if so desired. That's what the other arguments you're not using are used for.

Comment: Okay let me clear it. If I want to match any charcters(one or more) for the placeholders www.*.com , where * should be any character but shouldn't contain letter 'd' then what regular expression should I use @tadman

Comment: This has diverged pretty significantly from the original question, so I'd open up a new one focused on specifically that.

Comment: No, it is the same question. Please remove the answer as it does not answer the question.